# Status of the Hadamard Circulant conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

The following feels like a community wiki question, so I do it here:

Recently we have heard of a new proof of the Circulant Hadamard conjecture of Ryser
(a long standing difficult conjecture):

`There is no Circulant Hadamard matrix with more than $4$ columns`

see

Barry Hurley, Paul Hurley, Ted Hurley, The Hadamard circulant conjecture, Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 44, Issue 1, February 2012, Page 206, https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdq112

More recently  a gap was found in the proof:

see

[https://www.sfu.ca/~jed/Papers/Craigen%20Jedwab.%20Circulant%20Hadamard.%20Preprint.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejed/Papers/Craigen%20Jedwab.%20Circulant%20Hadamard.%20Preprint.pdf)

Question: What is the real status of this Conjecture ?

Comment: This is not my field, but I don't know of any progress since the case of 448 was done.

Comment: @Kimball: Your comment concerns the Hadamard Conjecture: For each
posotive integer $n$ multiple of $4$ there exist an Hadamard matrix
with $n$ columns. For both conjectures see the web wiki page that gives details on both, but not enough...

Comment: Given both articles are from 2011, I'd say you are as on top of the status as anyone could be.  Robert Craigen is approachable and (with the possible exception of Will Orrick) would be the first person I would ask about the conjecture.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.15

Comment: Kimball, if you mean 428, indeed, no new Hadamard matrices with new orders have been announced to me in the last 7 years.  If you mean 448 (= 28x16), you might check some (almost any) combinatorial design literature from the 20th century.  Gerhard "Slow, But Not That Slow" Paseman, 2011.02.15

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I mistyped.  I did mean 428.

Comment: It has been circulating around..

Comment: @unknowngoogle: Do you mean: Craigen and Jedwab's paper is under review ?


Comment: @Luis: according to Jedwab's website, his paper with Craigen has been submitted (it doesn't say where).

Answer (score 7):

The paper by Craigen and Jedwab points out a very definite flaw in the main theorem by Hurley, Hurley & Hurley, providing a counterexample to that theorem.  So the conjecture is still open.

The paper by Leung and Schmidt ([here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/5r4157r8244p31qw/)) gives the latest information about possible counterexamples to the Circulant Hadamard conjecture.

A [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20210719024610/https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/Bernhard/CW/CW.html) of Bernhard Schmidt lists smallest open cases based (I believe) on the work of the paper cited above.  The smallest open cases are, of course, quite large.

Comment: Interesting reference Ken.

Comment: The last link is broken. I found instead https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/bernhard/

Comment: The link to the paper is broken - but [searching in Google Scholer](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Leung+Schmidt+Circulant+Hadamard+conjecture) suggests that it was most likely this paper: _Leung, Ka Hin; Schmidt, Bernhard_, [**New restrictions on possible orders of circulant Hadamard matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10623-011-9493-1), Des. Codes Cryptography 64, No. 1-2, 143-151 (2012). [ZBL1242.15027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.15027).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunatly, there has been confusion about the status of this problem for decades.

All *correct* results on the circulant Hadamard matrix conjecture are contained in the following papers:

[1] Turyn, Richard J.: Character sums and difference sets. Pacific J. Math. 15 1965 319–346.

[2] Leung, Ka Hin; Schmidt, Bernhard: The field descent method. Des. Codes Cryptogr. 36 (2005), no. 2, 171–188.

[3] Leung, Ka Hin; Schmidt, Bernhard: New restrictions on possible orders of circulant Hadamard matrices. Des. Codes Cryptogr. 64 (2012), no. 1-2, 143–151.

Computational results and the latest status on the smallest open cases can be found in

[4] Peter Borwein, Michael J. Mossinghoff: Wieferich pairs and Barker sequences, II. 
arXiv:1306.0045v2

Bernhard Schmidt

Answer (score 6):

Craigen and Jedwab have indicated that the September 2011 revision of Hurley, Hurley & Hurley also has a flaw:

[https://www.sfu.ca/~jed/Papers/Craigen%20Jedwab.%20Circulant%20Hadamard%202.%20Preprint.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejed/Papers/Craigen%20Jedwab.%20Circulant%20Hadamard%202.%20Preprint.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

About two weeks ago, at the International Workshop on Hadamard Matrices and Their Applications (RMIT), http://user.gs.rmit.edu.au/asha/iwhma/ Jennifer Seberry presented a proof, based on counting arguments http://user.gs.rmit.edu.au/asha/iwhma/html/Wednesday/JenniferSeberry.pdf ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120317161911/http://user.gs.rmit.edu.au/asha/iwhma/html/Wednesday/JenniferSeberry.pdf)), but that proof was quickly found to be incomplete. As far as I know, she is currently working on improving the proof. A special volume of the Australasian Journal of Combinatorics http://user.gs.rmit.edu.au/asha/iwhma/html/ajc.html is forthcoming, and with any luck, things will become much clearer at that point.

Comment: this complements Penguian's post:
http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/11pub.html

gives:


JOURNAL ARTICLES SUBMITTED

Lei Wang, Tianbing Xia and Jennifer Seberry, UMAC for identifying IP spoofing attacks, (submitted)

Tianbing Xia, Jennifer Seberry and Mingyuan Xia, Some new constructions for orthogonal designs, (submitted)

Jennifer Seberry, Non-existence of circulant Hadamard matrices for orders $>$ 4 (submitted BLMS 17/11/11)

Jennifer Seberry, New families of amicable Hadamard matrices,

 

clicking on "Non-existence of circulant Hadamard matrices for orders $>$ 4 "


you get:



Comment: continued here:

You went from this referring page:
http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/11pub.html
To this missing page:
http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/WEB/WEB11/no-circ.17Nov.pdf 

Comment: Now, february 2012, above address changed contents to:  (in prep)
i.e., now seems that the paper, that has order number 10, become ``in preparation''... 

Answer (score 1):

On sep 4, 2011, authors Hurley, Hurley & Hurley of the paper on the Circulant Hadamard conjecture, has posted the same paper on the arxiv.  Did they corrected the error reported by Craigen and Jedwab on feb 10, 2011?

Comment: If you give a link, then this might help people to answer

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0748v1

Comment: @Chris: thanks, I now vaguely recall seeing this in the daily listings at the time. I note that the new/revised version makes no explicit reference that I can see to the earlier effort, nor to the Craigen and Jedwab paper

Comment: @Yemon: actually they state that it's a "post publication revision of on-line Bull. London Math. Soc. version", which is very delicately phrased. The lack of a reference to Craigen and Jedwab is a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

check:

Barry Hurley, Paul Hurley, Ted Hurley, The Hadamard circulant conjecture, Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 44, Issue 1, February 2012, Page 206, https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdq112

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out about this conjecture and found this paper from 2019 on arXiv,

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.12683.pdf

As far as I can tell, this paper is still unpublished and on the Wikipedia-page, it says that Circulant Matrix Conjecture is still an open problem. Is the proof in the aforementioned paper known to have gaps?

Comment: for what its worth, there's already a grammatical typo in the first page, and more appear in the next few pages. while that doesn't refute the paper at all, is is a red flag to me.

Comment: Some people like to look at the abstract, before deciding whether to load the pdf: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12683